# google translate bar not responsive on smaller screens

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, google-translate, translate

I've been working on this wordpress site that is using google translate, and i've used the script that you generate from google which translates your page and renders an iframe bar where you can disable it. Only problem is that the iframe is not responsive in smaller screens. The script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'sv'}, 
'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js? 
cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

You can also see an example of it here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_google_translate

The iframes content consists of table rows, which doesn't fit on a smaller screen. Does anyone know if there is there any workaround for making it responsive?

Comment: Why would you need an iframe when you can just use a div like the w3schools example?

Comment: i mean the top bar , iframe with the id of :1.container